# Sort on parent attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails app where users are assigned to projects as projectusers. Now I want to show a list of projects a user is assigned to. This works, but I also want to sort it on the customer name and then the project name. How can I do this?

So a customer has_many projects, a project has_many projectusers and a user has_many projectusers. And a projectuser belongs_to both an user and a project. Now I want to sort on customer.name and project.name. This is the method which ow returns the unsorted projects:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def active_projects(year=nil, month=nil, day=nil)
    self.projectusers.where("start_date <= ? and (end_date IS NULL or end_date >= ?)",    Date.new(year,month,day).end_of_month, Date.new(year,month,day))
  end
end
```

I probably need to include or join both projects and customers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you need to join projects and customers:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def active_projects(year=nil, month=nil, day=nil)
    self.
      projectusers.
      joins(projects: :customer).
      where("start_date <= ? and (end_date IS NULL or end_date >= ?)", Date.new(year,month,day).end_of_month, Date.new(year,month,day)).
      order("customers.name ASC, projects.name ASC")
  end
end
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, this works for projects, because that is a direct parent of projectuser. But for customer it doesn't work, because it is a parent of project instead of projectuser, so a level higher.

Comment: OH, I'm sorry, I misread your question! If you want to joins several tables one after the other you just need to use a hash: `joins(table1: {table2: table3}`. I edit my answer. I hope it's better